# Reading Json string from a JsonObject in android

Tags: android, json

I am having problems; I cannot read inner string from a jsonObject. It says JsonArray cannot be converted into JsonObject.

```
07-26 13:01:31.910 1798-1901/com.example.phuluso.aafs I/System.out: [{"AccommoAddress":{"AddressID":12,"City":"Johannesburg","InfoUrl":null,"Lattitude":"-26.181321","Longitude":"27.99158","PostalCode":2109,"Street":"22 Ararat Str","Town":"Westdene"},"AccommoDetails":null,"AccommoID":1,"AccommoImages":null,"AccommoName":"West Dunes Properties","AccommoType":"Flat","AccredStatus":"ACCREDITED","AddressId":12,"Capacity":9,"Distance":1,"EndDate":"2017-01-01","NearestCampus":"APK","OwnerId":0,"StartDate":"2016-01-01"}]
```

Here's my JsonArray.  I am trying to read from AccommoAddress, but I get the  error below:

```
[{"AccommoAddress":{"AddressID":12,"City":"Johannesburg","InfoUrl":null,"Lattitude":"-26.181321","Longitude":"27.99158","PostalCode":2109,"Street":"22 Ararat Str","Town":"Westdene"},"AccommoDetails":null,"AccommoID":1,"AccommoImages":null,"AccommoName":"West Dunes Properties","AccommoType":"Flat","AccredStatus":"ACCREDITED","AddressId":12,"Capacity":9,"Distance":1,"EndDate":"2017-01-01","NearestCampus":"APK","OwnerId":0,"StartDate":"2016-01-01"}]
```

Here's my code

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        List<AccommoNearAPK> data = new ArrayList<>();
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        try
        {
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("AccommoAddress");

            /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

            int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

            for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
            {
                /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                /******* Fetch node values **********/
                String name       = jsonChildNode.optString("Street");
                String number     = jsonChildNode.optString("City");
                String date_added = jsonChildNode.optString("Longitude");
                String lat = jsonChildNode.optString("Lattitude");

                System.out.print("Street"+ name + "City" +number+ "Long" + date_added+" Lat" + lat);

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, date_added + name + number + lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a json array in data and you try to parse it as `new JSONObject(result)` seems pretty obvious

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your response is a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`, similarly, `AccommoAddress` is a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`. So you need to change the lines near the top to the following:

```
 JSONArray jsonResponse = null;

 try
 {
     jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);
     JSONObject jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("AccommoAddress");
```

Comment: Please don't answer such obvious dupes

Answer (score 0):

"AccommoAddress" is a JSONObject not a JSONArray. So instead of this..

```
JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("AccommoAddress");
```

Try this ..

```
/*String Accommo = jsonResponse.getString("AccommoAddress");
JSONObject AccomoAddress = new JSONObject(Accommo);*/
//simplifying the above code
JSONObject Accomoaddress = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("AccomoAddress");
String name = AccomoAddress.getString("Street");
String number = AccomoAddress.getString("City");
String date_added = AccomoAddress.getString("Longitude");
String lat = AccomoAddress.getString("Lattitude");
```